# Android Adapting ImageView Size to Screen Size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a specific layout that I want to achieve, but I can't figure out how to make it work robustly across multiple screen sizes.

The key idea is that the information in the TextViews is important, and the ImageView is decorative. I want the ImageView to be resized according to the users screen size (up to a maximum size). Also, I want all elements to stay grouped together so that they don't appear sparse on large screens. I would prefer to find a solution in xml, but am open to anything that will do the job.

Here's what I'm after (I can't post images here yet):

On small screens the imageview shrinks:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29549935/small_screen.png

On large screens imageview meets a max value (should be handled by scaling automatically), and the content is kept together in the screen's center:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29549935/large_screen.png

I have tried a lot of options that I thought should have worked, for instance, the code below positions the textviews relative to the imageview, all grouped together in a relativelayout. This works well on large screens, however on small screens the textviews are pushed out of the way by the imageview:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageview1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/textview1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="256dp"
            android:maxWidth="256dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/mydrawable" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview1"

            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/textview2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/textview3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It seems like this way could work if it is stipulated that the imageview can take up a proportion of the relativelayout.

Any help very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to create images for separate screen resolution and put it in drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi folders....`, such as

```
drawable-ldpi  - Low dpi  (Low size screen Resolution)

drawable-mdpi  - Medium dpi (Medium size screen Resolution)

drawable-hdpi  - High dpi,  (large size screen Resolution)

drawable-xhdpi - Extended High dpi (For tablest and wide screen)
```

And also you should take care of density of the image

[multiple screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Sample App and ABout density etc ...](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

[Multiple screen support design](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)